# NEO4J Cypher find nodes with multiple relationship counts

Tags: neo4j, cypher

## Graph

I've got a Neo4J database with broadly three types of graphs that look something like this:

1. A single cat, fed by one human, who lives in one building.
   [image: Graph 1]
2. A single cat, fed by two humans, who live in the same building
   [image: Same cat, different humans, same building]
3. A single cat, who is being fed by multiple humans who all live in different buildings
   [image: Same cat, different humans, and different buildings]

## Query

The data has lots of small graphs of this kind. I want to select the graphs where the Cat is fed by more humans than the humans have buildings. `count(cat fed by human) > count(human lives in building)` for each graph.

To select cats with multiple humans I can run:

```
MATCH (cat:CAT)-[fed_by:FED_BY]-(:Human)
WITH cat, count(fed_by) as n_feeders
WHERE n_feeders > 1
MATCH g=(cat)-[:FED_BY]-(:Person)-[:LIVES_AT]-(:Building)
RETURN g
LIMIT 10
```

But how can I add the condition that the number of `(:Cat)-[:FED_BY]-(:Human)` relationships must be greater than the number of `(:Human)-[:LIVES_IN]-(:Building)` relationships?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Cats you are looking for with the following query.

You can return the graph for these cats at the end.

```
MATCH (cat:CAT)-[:FED_BY]-(person:Person)-[:LIVES_AT]-(building:Building)
WITH cat, COUNT(DISTINCT person) as n_feeders, COUNT(DISTINCT building) as n_buildings
WHERE n_feeders > n_buildings
RETURN cat
```